# How to disable editing my history in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

In bash, when I go back in history, edit some command and run it, this edited command is appended to history and the original one is left intact. But every once in a while I somehow manage to affect the original command, i.e. my edit replaces the original command back in history. I can't put my finger on how this happens.

Can someone explain? My goal is to avoid this, so any edit to a previous command always gets appended to history and never replaces the original.

Comment: How are you editing, 'fc -e vi'?

Comment: I avoid this by some kind of unconscious key mashing. I'd really like to know the answer.

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154777/how-to-stop-bash-editing-the-history-when-i-reuse-and-modify-an-entry

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl + C` skips changing the original command -- [relevant discussion in Unix & Linux SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131657/is-there-any-way-to-undo-a-bash-history-modification#comment210887_131657).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I somehow manage to affect the original command, i.e. my edit replaces the original command back in history.

Right.  If you go back in your history and edit the line *without* pressing return to execute the command but instead moving to another history entry, you've just *edited* the history entry.  If you then list your history, you will see a `*` on the line indicating that you edited it.  I find this "feature" immensely frustrating.  Others have provided good examples of how to reproduce this.

> My goal is to avoid this, so any edit to a previous command always gets appended to history and never replaces the original.

I too wanted to disable it.  I found the solution via [this answer over on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299563/16711).

To summarize, you need to enable the `revert-all-at-newline` readline setting which is off by default.  If the setting is on then bash will revert any changes you made to your history when you execute the next command.

To enable this setting in your shell, you should add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file and then restart your shell:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
set revert-all-at-newline on
```

The first line is needed because I guess that if you supply your own `.inputrc` file the default `/etc/inputrc` file is not included which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It prevents that spurious editing, which seems like good behavior that should have been the default.

Comment: I can't believe this feature exists. I spent a few minutes thinking I was going crazy because the command I JUST TYPED 2 MINUTES AGO was somehow gone, because I had navigated back to it and made a small but key change that stopped me recognizing it.

Answer (score 7):

If you go back to some previous command and edit it, but then DON'T execute it (instead using history commands to go to some other command and execute it), then the edits will remain there in your history list.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, after editing, counters this behaviour.  It leaves the original command in tact i.e. it cancels remembering edits to the original.

Comment: BUT if you go back to the same command and execute it (with or without further editing), the history gets restored back.
IF, on the other hand, you exit bash, then those edits get recorded permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my own answer, please correct or provide more details if you can.

When the "vi" option is set in bash ("set -o vi" -- "Use a vi-style command line editing interface"), there are two modes of editing a command from history.

The first mode (let's call it "basic") is when you start editing immediately using Backspace, Del and character keys.

The other mode is the "vi mode", entered when you hit Esc.

If you want to keep your history intact, DO NOT use both modes in the same edit. I don't know how bash works exactly, but you can think of it this way:

1. Entering the "vi mode" applies any changes done in "basic mode" to the original command, and creates a copy of the command that you can edit further using vi-style commands.
2. The changes get applied when you hit Enter (execute), Up, Down or j,k (move to another command in history).
3. The changes do not get applied if you hit Ctrl-C.
4. Using either basic or vi-style editing ALONE does not affect the original command in history.

Answer (score 1):

What do

```
echo $HISTCONTROL
echo $HISTIGNORE
```

give you?

**Edit:**

I was able to reproduce behavior similar to what you've seen by following these steps:

- At the shell prompt, enter:

  `echo abcd`
  `echo efgh`
- Press up arrow twice, so "echo abcd" is shown
- Press 1 to add that character at the end
- Press escape to enter command mode
- Press left arrow twice so the cursor is on the "c"
- Press x to delete the "c"
- Press enter

Now as you step back through history, you'll see a new entry at the end:

```
echo abd1
```

and the entry that previously had "echo abcd" will now look like this:

```
echo abcd1
```

This is one way, I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Blanks. I don't have those defined. I don't think it's anything to do with settings. It's not consistent. If you ask me to repeat it, I won't be able to. I think I do this by accidentally hitting some vi combination. My editor is set by "set -o vi".