# How can I recall a command using ! without executing it immediately?

Tags: bash

In Bash, typing for example `!make` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> will recall and also execute the last command that starts with "make" in the history.

What I'd like is to just recall that command, but not evaluate it right away until I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, to allow me to look at it, or edit it if needed.

Is there a way to do that in Bash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458793/editing-history-in-bash may have what you want

Comment: ctrl-r or ctrl-shift-r ?

Comment: Arguably, this isn't a programming question at all, and doesn't belong on SO -- history expansion (the feature this question is about) is for interactive use, not for scripts.

Comment: Same trick works as in (t)csh: use the `:p` modifier: `!make:p` or `!?search?:p`.

Comment: @Nasser: good to hear.  don't worry about it.

Comment: You should use zsh, it has an option for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to get the previous command

You can also use <kbd>CRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to reverse search for a command in your history.

Answer (score 3):

The `p` modifier after any history expansion prints the result to the command line for further editing, rather than executing it.

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ !!:p
$ echo foo
          ^
          |
          cursor remains here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand history on the current line using the `history-expand-line` key (`M-^`).

The `M` modifier key is usually mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

```
$ !make
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

```
$ make -C mydir
```

if your last `make` command was `make -C mydir`.  You can then edit the command line in place.

Alternatively, you can scroll through history as outlined in other answers.