# Prevent accidental history editing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, edit, history

I recently switched from tcsh to bash, and one thing that keeps tripping me up is how bash handles history.  I regularly bring up a previous history command and begin to edit it, but realize I need to run a different command first.  In bash, this edits the original command, and I cannot see what I originally typed. In tcsh, the edited command is at the bottom of the stack when I use the up and down arrows, and is ready to continue editing or run when I am ready for it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458793/editing-history-in-bash), which had several answers helpful in understanding how bash works in regards to rerunning and editing history, but I still don't know of a way to change this behavior (if such a thing exists).  Is it possible to prevent bash from editing the commands that have already been run?

For example, if I run

```
  abcd
  efgh
  ijkl
```

And then use arrow up and backspace efgh to efg, then hit down and type a different command "mnop", I want my history to look like:

```
  abcd
  efgh
  ijkl
  mnop
```

Currently it looks like:

```
  abcd
* efg
  ijkl
  mnop
```

This may seem like a trivial issue but when running long commands with multiple pipes that require trial and error, it is some substantial loss of work.

Comment: Don't hit down, press Ctrl+c.

Comment: Thanks - that is good to know.  Sometimes I may forget this, but between this and chepner's answer I should be in much better shape.

Comment: Yes this is a very serious nuisance. History conceptually and *by definition* should be immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line maintains its own undo list which you can access with `C-x C-u`  or `C-_` to undo the most recent change, or `M-r` to revert all changes since it was last saved.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks for sharing.  How would I go about finding more shortcuts like this?  None of this came up when I searched for "bash history edit" or "bash history", and it seems that reverting the history is impossible to do without these keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Read about the `bind` built-in command and read the `Readline` section fo the man page. Many functions have default bindings, but you can use `bind` to either change them or add bindings for commands that aren't bound by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to prevent bash from editing the commands that have already been run?

It is possible to to prevent this "feature".  I found the solution via [this answer over on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299563/16711).

To summarize, you need to enable the `revert-all-at-newline` readline setting which is off by default.  If the setting is on then bash will revert any changes you made to your history when you execute the next command.

To enable this setting in your shell, you should add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file and then restart your shell:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
set revert-all-at-newline on
```

The first line is needed because I guess that if you supply your own `.inputrc` file the default `/etc/inputrc` file is not included which is probably not what you want.